# Custom projection with mapnik

Tags: coordinate-system, mapnik

I would like to superimpose openstreetmap data over a raster image, using mapnik.
My problem is that this image is not in a projection being defined by a SRS, I have some non-linear algorithm to run to be able to match a pixel and a geographic position.

Is it possible to use some kind of custom converter for positions in mapnik ?

Another possibility would be to modify every longitude/latitude in the database to set them to the corresponding pixels, but I'm afraid that it won't play well with the internal reprojections in mapnik.

I still have the possibility to do everything by hand using the OSM API, but the result would be ugly.

The processing will be done in python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally did it by hand. The hardest part was finding non outdated informations about OSM and the library ecosystem.

Comment: Could you share how you did this?